# Groovy assertion on SOAP UI for database output

Tags: groovy, automation, soapui

Using SOAP UI I am running query and fetching data for an specific ID and after that I want to validate specific field and its corresponding Value which is returning .
*Ex -* 
**Version =2** 
So I want to validate that every time for the generated record the version is 2 .

I checked and came up with the below code but the Select query is giving me error ,where it is unable to read value returning from **recordId** variable which i am using in Where condition ,So how to resolve it ?

The below is the database result which i want to validate 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpeZh.png)

```
 def listOfPostedRecordIds = parser.parseText(context.expand( '${1.CreateTestData#IdsToBeDeleted}' ))

 def **recordId**=listOfPostedRecordIds[0] 

log.info "recordId is "+recordId 

def Version = myDB.firstRow('''Select cast(("Research"."meta"#>>'{versionId}') as integer)as Version from "Research"where id= **("recordId")** ''') 

log.info  "The value of  is ${Version}
```

Comment: can anyone please answer ?

Comment: Please post your Groovy code so that we can help you.

Comment: @ou_ryperd Actually I am new to groovy and tying to figure it out how to but unable to do ,so if you can give some insight or sample example then it would be great or else some other way to validate ..

Comment: @ou_ryperd 
I checked and came up with the below but the Select query is giving me error ,where it is unable to read value from recordId variable which i am using in Where condition  ,So how to resolve it ?

def listOfPostedRecordIds = parser.parseText(context.expand( '${1.CreateTestData#IdsToBeDeleted}' )) 

def recordId=listOfPostedRecordIds[0]

log.info "recordId is "+recordId

def Version = myDB.firstRow('''Select cast(("ResearchSubject"."meta"#>>'{versionId}') as integer)as Version from "ResearchSubject"where id= ("recordId") ''')
log.info  "The value of  is ${Version} "

Comment: Hi ou_ryperd  ,
I have edited the body of my question and question starts from 
"Question is " in same thread 
kindly check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parameterize data in your SQL in Groovy, do it with a ? like this:

```
def recordId = listOfPostedRecordIds[0]

def Version = myDB.firstRow("""
    Select cast(('ResearchSubject'.'meta'#>>'{versionId}') as integer) as Version
    from 'ResearchSubject'
    where id = ?;""", [recordId])

log.info "The value of is ${Version}"
```

Also note that your select is quite complicated with ", ', # >> and {}. Make sure all those are really required.

Comment: What does the ? Mean here ?

Comment: Thank you now its working ,another question is how can i do assertion that the result which is returning from db result  is 1 and correct ?

Comment: It's the placeholder that will be replaced by the variable in [] at execution. You don't need all those quotes around table and field names in your query, only for literal strings.

Comment: Thank you now its working ,     another question is how can i do assertion that the result which is returning from db result  is 1 and correct ?

Comment: `assert Version == 1` It will only output if it asserts to false. If you want a SoapUI assertion, I think it only works out of the box on messages, not custom code like you have here. Try https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions/

Comment: I tried with the assert Version==1 and works fine ,Thank you Very much for you help ,I appreciate it . :)

Comment: ou_ryperd ,Do you have any link where i can learn the how and when to use  ' and "  ?

Comment: ou_ryperd
 Do you have any link where i can learn the how and when to use ' and " ?

Comment: It is by convention. I always use tableName.fieldName. SQL code generators often add [tableName].[fieldName] (ms-sql does this) or "tableName"."fieldname" (mysql does this). It is less confusing to just use tableName.fieldName, especially if you mix SQL with other languages. You use ' to denote literasl strings in SQL, and also for concatenating strings etc.